# Select the most elements that do not overlap so that the sum of their size is maximized

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, combinatorics, network-flow

I'm trying to find an algorithm to the following problem.

Say I have a number of objects A, B, C,...

I have a list of valid combinations of these objects. Each combination is of length 2 or 4.

For eg. AF, CE, CEGH, ADFG,... and so on.

For combinations of two objects, eg. AF, the length of the combination is 2. For combination of four objects, eg CEGH, the length of the combination.

I can only pick non-overlapping combinations, i.e. I cannot pick AF and ADFG because both require objects 'A' and 'F'. I can pick combinations AF and CEGH because they do not require common objects.
If my solution consists of only the two combinations AF and CEGH, then my objective is the sum of the length of the combinations, which is 2 + 4 = 6.

Given a list of objects and their valid combinations, how do I pick the most valid combinations that don't overlap with each other so that I maximize the sum of the lengths of the combinations? I do not want to formulate it as an IP as I am working with a problem instance with 180 objects and 10 million valid combinations and solving an IP using CPLEX is prohibitively slow. Looking for some other elegant way to solve it. Can I perhaps convert this to a network? And solve it using a max-flow algorithm? Or a Dynamic program? Stuck as to how to go about solving this problem.

Comment: "CEGH, the length of the combination." ​ -> ​ "CEGH, the length of the combination is 4." ​ ​ ​ ? ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Consider the undirected graph on the objects give by [[X is adjacent to Y] if and only if [XY is a subset of at least one valid combination]]. ​ (You can build that graph with just one pass through your valid combinations.) ​ Is that graph connected? ​ If it's not, then you can easily split your problem into strictly smaller disjoint subproblems. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: If it is connected, then compute vertex capacities as ​ log ( 1 + number of valid combinations that object is in ) ​ and edge capacities as ​ log ( 1 + number of valid combinations the edge is a subset of ) ​ and try [contracting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_contraction#Vertex_cleaving) disjoint probably-but-not-necessarily-connected and using [generalized max-flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem#Generalized_max-flow_min-cut_theorem). ​ (Those capacities can be computed with just one pass through your valid combinations.) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: When you get not-too-high flows, try growing the to-be-contracted subgraphs. ​ If you can make both subgraphs fairly large without allowing too much flow, then you can reduce your problem to not-too-many significantly smaller subproblems. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer Thanks for the answer - could you direct me to somewhere where this is explained in more detail (if it exists)? Perhaps with an example?

Comment: I'm not aware of any such place. ​ Suppose your set of objects splits into disjoint sets S0 and S1 such that the graph I initially described has no edges from S0 to S1. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ In that case, you just combine a solution to ​ ​ ​ ( ​ S0 ​ , ​ valid combinations of S0's objects ​ ) ​ ​ ​ with a solution to ​ ​ ​ ( ​ S1 ​ , ​ valid combinations of S1's objects ​ ) ​ ​ ​ since there are no objects that combine both, so there's no interaction. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: If you instead have a low-capacity cut, then there's just _little_ interaction - You can brute-force over [for each vertex/edge in the cut, do you use a combination involving that, and if so which one], and then solve the use my previous comment to solve the disconnected problem that results from those choices. ​ ​

Comment: Please un-tick my first answer (which is incorrect) so that I can delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first attempt at showing this problem to be NP-hard was wrong, as it did not take into account the fact that only combinations of size 2 or 4 were allowed.  However, using [Jim D.'s suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011832/select-the-most-elements-that-do-not-overlap-so-that-the-sum-of-their-size-is-ma#comment71255807_42035554) to reduce from [3-dimensional matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011832/select-the-most-elements-that-do-not-overlap-so-that-the-sum-of-their-size-is-ma#comment71255807_42035554) (3DM), we can show that the problem is nevertheless NP-hard.

I'll show that the natural decision problem form of your problem ("Given a set O of objects, and a set C of combinations of either 2 or 4 objects from O, and an integer m, does there exist a subset D of C such that all sets in D are pairwise disjoint, and the union of all sets in D has size at least m?") is NP-hard.  Clearly the optimisation problem (i.e., your original problem, where we seek an actual subset of combinations that maximises m above) is at least as hard as this problem.  (To see that the optimisation problem is not "much" harder than the decision problem, notice that you could first find the maximum m value for which a solution exists using a binary search on m in which you solve a decision problem at each step, and then, once this maximal m value has been found, solving a series of decision problems in which each combination in turn is removed: if the solution after removing some particular combination is still "YES", then it may also be left out of all future problem instances, while if the solution becomes "NO", then it is necessary to keep this combination in the solution.)

Given an instance (X, Y, Z, T, k) of 3DM, where X, Y and Z are sets that are pairwise disjoint from each other, T is a subset of X*Y*Z (i.e., a set of ordered triples with first, second and third components from X, Y and Z, respectively) and k is an integer, our task is to determine whether there is any subset U of T such that |U| >= k and all triples in U are pairwise disjoint (i.e., to answer the question, "Are there at least k non-overlapping triples in T?").  To turn any such instance of 3DM into an instance of your problem, all we need to do is create a fresh 4-combination from each triple in T, by adding a distinct dummy value to each.  The set of objects in the constructed instance of your problem will consist of the union of X, Y, Z, and the |T| dummy values we created.  Finally, set m to k.

Suppose that the answer to the original 3DM instance is "YES", i.e., there are at least k non-overlapping triples in T.  Then each of the k triples in such a solution corresponds to a 4-combination in the input C to your problem, and no two of these 4-combinations overlap, since by construction, their 4th elements are all distinct, and by assumption of the.  Thus there are at least m = k non-overlapping 4-combinations in the instance of your problem, so the solution for that problem must also be "YES".

In the other direction, suppose that the solution to the constructed instance of your problem is "YES", i.e., there are at least m non-overlapping 4-combinations in C.  We can simply take the first 3 elements of each of the 4-combinations (throwing away the fourth) to produce a set of k = m non-overlapping triples in T, so the answer to the original 3DM instance must also be "YES".

We have shown that a YES-answer to one problem implies a YES-answer to the other, thus a NO-answer to one problem implies a NO-answer to the other.  Thus the problems are equivalent.  The instance of your problem can clearly be constructed in polynomial time and space.  It follows that your problem is NP-hard.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce this problem to the [maximum weighted clique problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem), which is, unfortunately, NP-hard.

Build a graph such that every combination is a vertex with weight equal to the length of the combination, and connect vertices if the corresponding combinations do not share any object (i.e. if you can pick both them at the same time). Then, a solution is valid if and only if it is a clique in that graph.

A simple search on google brings up a lot of approximation algorithms for this problem, such as [this one](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10732-007-9026-2).

Comment: @JimD. what do you mean?

Comment: @JimD. "if and only if" work both directions. In other words, the set of cliques are all the valid solutions, and no other valid solution (that is not a clique) exist

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you showed that given an instance of OPs problem, you can convert it to an instance of maximum weighted clique.  To show that OPs problem is NP-hard, don't you need to show an instance of maximum weighted clique can be transformed into an instance of OPs problem?  We already knew any problem in NP can be transformed to an instance of max wighted clique in polynomial time because it is NP complete.

Comment: @JimD. okay, I see what you mean, I didn't realize that. I will try to come up with a correct proof, if it exists

Comment: I would suggest trying to reduce [3-dimensional matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-dimensional_matching) to the OPs problem.  If you can do this, this would have some interesting implications with respect to approximation algorithms.